# Plot Complex Function

Tags: plotting, complex

I want to have a 3D plot for the following function:
(1.6 - 0.005 I) E^(-0.5 p^2 + ( 2. I) p q + (6.5 - 11 q) q)
p and q from -10 to 10

Is there any way?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site. Here its considered helpful to share your code attempts, hopefully is a [well formatted](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) way.
Do you want to plot only of the real part? Please explain further what do you expect as an output.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an interesting way to do it using complex phase-amplitude plots:

```
hue = Compile[{{z, _Complex}}, {(1.0 Arg[-z] + \[Pi])/(2 \[Pi]), 
    Exp[1 - Max[Abs[z], 1]], Min[Abs[z], 1]}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
ComplexPlot[f_, {x0_, x1_, \[Delta]x_}, {y0_, y1_, \[Delta]y_}] := 
  Image[hue[
     f[#[[All, All, 1]], #[[All, All, 2]]] &@
      Outer[List, Range[x0, x1, \[Delta]x], 
       Range[y0, y1, \[Delta]y]]]\[Transpose], ColorSpace -> Hue, 
   Magnification -> 1];
ComplexPlot[f_, {x0_, x1_, \[Delta]x_}, {y0_, y1_, \[Delta]y_}, 
   mag_] := 
  Image[hue[
     mag f[#[[All, All, 1]], #[[All, All, 2]]] &@
      Outer[List, Range[x0, x1, \[Delta]x], 
       Range[y1, y0, -\[Delta]y]]]\[Transpose], ColorSpace -> Hue, 
   Magnification -> 1];
CCompile[expr_] := 
  Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, Evaluate[expr], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
```

Then execute the following:

```
f = (1.6 - 
      0.005 I) E^(-0.5 p^2 + (2. I) p q + (6.5 - 11 q) q) /. {p -> x, 
    q -> y};
ComplexPlot[CCompile[f], {-2, 2, 0.005}, {-0.8, 1.2, 0.005}, 0.3]
```

which produces the following plot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since the function is complex valued, you have to find its real and imaginary and plot these. This type of question has been asked before many times, so I am sure this is duplicate.

```
Clear[p, q]
f = (1.6 - 0.005 I) E^(-0.5 p^2 + (2. I) p q + (6.5 - 11 q) q)
p1 = Plot3D[Re@f, {p, -2, 2}, {q, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
p2 = Plot3D[Im@f, {p, -2, 2}, {q, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @Nasser's answer

```
f = (1.6 - 0.005 I) E^(-0.5 p^2 + (2. I) p q + (6.5 - 11 q) q);

Partition[
  Plot3D[#[f],
     {p, -2, 2}, {q, -2, 2},
     PlotRange -> All,
     PlotPoints -> 51,
     AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
        {p, 
         q, #["f"]})] & /@
   {Re, Im, Abs, Arg}, 2] // Grid
```

[image]